# igraph trouble upon install in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: ubuntu, installation, rstudio, igraph

I'm new to `igraph` and still green on `R` ('littler' version 0.3.2, with `R` v3.4.0)  and `Rstudio` (Version 1.0.153).
I just installed `R` and `Rstudio` and am experiencing problems when installing igraph on Ubuntu 17.04 (64bits). This question was asked [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45318188/getting-error-in-function-igraph-write-graph-graphml-while-installing-igrap) but was not solved and has no accepted answer.

The install error described below seems to be independent of the library directory in which I try to install the package. I tried both:
     ... by modifying the file `/etc/R/Renviron`.

The result from within RStudio is in each case:

```
> install.packages("igraph")
........
In file included from src/foreign-gml-parser.y:59:0:
igraph_hacks_internal.h:42:0: warning: "strdup" redefined
 #  define strdup igraph_i_strdup

In file included from /usr/include/string.h:630:0,
                 from src/foreign-gml-parser.y:54:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string2.h:337:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #   define strdup(s) __strdup (s)

gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -DUSING_R -I. -Iinclude -Ics -Iglpk -Iplfit -ICHOLMOD/Include -IAMD/Include -ICOLAMD/Include -ISuiteSparse_config -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-X2xP8j/r-base-3.4.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -DNDEBUG -DNPARTITION -DNTIMER -DNCAMD -DNPRINT -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"1.1.1\" -DINTERNAL_ARPACK -DIGRAPH_THREAD_LOCAL=/**/ -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-X2xP8j/r-base-3.4.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c foreign-graphml.c -o foreign-graphml.o
foreign-graphml.c: In function ‘igraph_write_graph_graphml’:
foreign-graphml.c:1408:46: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘GRAPHML_NAMESPACE_URI’
   ret=fprintf(outstream, "<graphml xmlns=\"" GRAPHML_NAMESPACE_URI "\"\n");
                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
foreign-graphml.c:1412:59: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘GRAPHML_NAMESPACE_URI’
   ret=fprintf(outstream, "         xsi:schemaLocation=\"" GRAPHML_NAMESPACE_URI "\n");
                                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
foreign-graphml.c:1414:38: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘GRAPHML_NAMESPACE_URI’
   ret=fprintf(outstream, "         " GRAPHML_NAMESPACE_URI "/1.0/graphml.xsd\">\n");
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:159: recipe for target 'foreign-graphml.o' failed
make: *** [foreign-graphml.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘igraph’
* removing ‘/home/ckb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/igraph’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘igraph’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmpli2vyo/downloaded_packages’
```

I'd be most grateful if anyone could help me with a fix. A certain famous Search Engine was not particularly helpful, possibly because I did not know how to look for an answer.
 Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround was to install the package for all users instead of doing so only for one user from within an Rstudio session. I am not clear at all on why I systematically get an error when attempting the latter.
The cli in Ubuntu was:

```
sudo su - -c "R -e \"install.packages('igraph', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')\""
```

Comment: Worked for me (Lubuntu 16.04, R 3.5.2). Thank you!